# Google Charts - SteppedArea Chart - Show Values?

Tags: google-visualization

I have googled and googled, and searched Stack Overflow, but i cant seem to find my answer;

I have a page full of Google Charts, showing the annotations on each graph (lines, columns, gauges etc).

I have added a Stepped Area Chart, and for some reason I cannot seem to get the annotations to show up.

My code is below:

```
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
        data.addColumn('number', 'For Today');
        data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
        data.addColumn('number', 'For Tomorrow');
        data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
        data.addColumn('number', 'Beyond Tomorrow');
        data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});

    data.addRows([
      ['3 hours ago',     84,84,         79,79,     22,22],
      ['2 hours ago',     69,69,         29,29,     45,45],
      ['Last Hour',       65,65,         40,40,     15,15],
      ['This hour',       30,30,         18,18,     4,4]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: '(Alternative Visualization) Order Drop In',
      vAxis: {title: 'Total Orders'},
      isStacked: true,
      chartArea: {  width: '50%', height: '70%' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('alt_order_drop_in'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

The weird thing is that the graph shows on the page perfectly fine, just no values are shown.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The SteppedAreaCharts do not support annotations.  You can make a feature request to add support [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Post it as answer and I will mark it as the answer for future googlers to find :)

(I will also submit a feature request)

Comment: It's too short - SO will automatically convert it to a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment "The SteppedAreaCharts do not support annotations. You can make a feature request to add support [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/). –" Posted by @asgallant

A request for this feature has been posted [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1459&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)